# Runtime.getRuntime.exec() hangs on same command that it runs in different situations

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I'm having an interesting problem when I use Runtime.getRuntime.exec() to run a command from Java. The following part of my code basically converts doc file to txt file. catdoc is a tool that converts input file to text stream and outputs it to the standard output. The ouput than redirected to a txt file. It works perfectly fine for some document files, however it hangs for some certain document files.

```
String[] strArr1 = new String[]{"catdoc", docFilePath};
Process p1= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(strArr1);
p1.waitFor();

BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));
FileWriter writeoutStream = new java.io.FileWriter(file.txt);

while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
    writeoutStream.write(line);
    writeoutStream.write('\n');
}
writeoutStream.close();
b.close();
```

I have many document files and this code segment works on some of the files but it hangs on one of the files and doesn't respond. I doubt that this may be cause by the size of the document file. Is that possible? I was wondering if there is any way that I could solve this problem.

**Update**: I know which files causes runtime to freeze. I tried using the catdoc command on those files, it produces correct result. So, nothing is wrong with the input files.

Comment: first find the document that it hangs on, and try to run the command only on this document to find a specific error... anyway my guess is that it is running the command in a document that doesn't exist

Comment: I did it. The same command runs and produces desired results in terminal for the file that runtime.exec() hangs on. I'll update my question.

Comment: 'p1.getErrorStream()' check if there is any error in this InputStream

Comment: @fmodos no error message is generated. Basically, program hangs on the line `Process p1= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(strArr1);`

Comment: can you post the strArr1 value of the command that doesn't run? what are the values in the array?

Comment: @fmodos value of strArr1[0] = "catdoc" and value of strArr1[1] = "filename.doc"

Answer (score 2):

If you call `Process.waitFor()` before consuming all the output, the process can block trying to produce it. Move the `waitFor()` after the reading code.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, but have you tried running the `catdoc` command in your process with the `-b` flag?

> -b
>   - process broken MS-Word file. Normally, catdoc checks if first 8 bytes of file is Microsoft OLE signature. If so, it processes file,
>   otherwise it just copies it to stdin. It is intended to use catdoc as
>   filter for viewing all files with .doc extension.

Comment: I don't thing it's related to catdoc. I have the same problem for converting pdf files to txt files. As I mentioned in my question, I think this is related to internal of Runtime.getRuntime.exec().

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all the proposed solutions here and other places but there was no help for Runtime.exec(). It seems, this is an internal buffer size problem in Runtime command. I found the same problem that runtime.exec() hangs. The problem was clearly described in the java docs which I just learned.

“Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, and even deadlock.”

Therefore, I decided to use ProcessBuilder instead of Runtime. It completely solved my problem. Below is the code I used for my problem:

```
String[] strArr1 = new String[]{"catdoc", docFilePath};
ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder( strArr1 );
Process process = probuilder.start();

InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

FileWriter writeoutStream = new java.io.FileWriter(file.txt);

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    writeoutStream.write(line);
    writeoutStream.write('\n');
}
writeoutStream.close();
br.close();
isr.close();
is.close();

//Wait to get exit value
try {
    int exitVal = process.waitFor();
    System.out.println("\n\nExit Value is " + exitVal);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code works perfectly fine with different type of commands (short or long) and on different size of files (large or small). My problem is completely solved.

Comment: You also need to consume the standard error stream, either in a separate thread or by merging the streams.

Comment: I think you might be confused. The difference between `Runtime.exec()` vs `ProcessBuilder`, is the `p1.waitFor();` that you had in your initial implementation. That was causing your problem. If you add this to your `ProcessBuilder`-based implementation, you will end up with the same issue.