# CMD command gets stuck when called from a minimal java program

Tags: java, windows, command-line

I have a simple command `CMD /C xyz --abc D:/temp/asd.txt` which successfully executes from command prompt. Now I put it in a simple java project with one class and it stops in between. The process don't end it gets hanged in there.

```
Process process= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
try (final BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()))) {
        String line;

        while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
}
```

I even tried it with ProcessBuilder. It's the same always.

With CMD it prints almost around 1000 lines with a particular message at last. With java code it hangs around 800 lines. What could be the possible reason? How to resolve this?

Comment: Why do you read only the errorStream? Can the 200 missing lines be in the inputStream? I would create two buffer readers one with ErrorStream and one with InputStream and would try to debug from there

Comment: @IoannisBarakos I was playing with it while pasting it here. I printed inputstream as well. It didn't run properly. I have one sysout statement once command gets executed, it prints. It's been an hour, that line isn't printed. Doesn't matter if the command produces an error or a result, the sysout is after i called waitFor(). It is stuck.

Comment: Have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851745/runtime-getruntime-exec-hangs-on-same-command-that-it-runs-in-different-situat  ?

Comment: What is `xyz --abc`?

Comment: @Eugen Covaci. Doesn't matter. I wrote it as an example. There is a command which works fine when fired in cmd but, gets stuck in between when fired from some java code.